# Get list out of other list

Tags: python

For some reason I end up with having a "list within a list" which does not really make sense to me:

I got a variable which contains the following output:

```
>>> print(combined_result)
>>> [[('id1', 'titel1'), ('id2', 'titel2'), ('id3', 'titel3'), ('id3', 'titel4')]]
```

which is generated by the following code:

```
combined_result = []
def executequery(cursor):
        cursor.execute("SELECT id, title FROM database")
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        result = records
        combined_result.append(result)
        return
```

To actually get the first element of that combined list I call it with:

```
>>> print(combined_result[0][1])
>>> ('id1', 'titel1')
```

I am wondering whether this is the right way to do it? Or should I modify my code? It is a bit weird right to have a list within a list in my situation?

Comment: i suggest you use ORM like peewee.

Answer (score 1):

Just after the function add this

```
>>> combined_result=combined_result[0]
```

Output

```
>>> combined_result
[('id1', 'titel1'), ('id2', 'titel2'), ('id3', 'titel3'), ('id3', 'titel4')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You just don't need `combined_result` as `result` is already a list. You can return `result` from your function.

```
combined_result = []
def executequery(cursor):
    cursor.execute("SELECT id, title FROM database")
    return cursor.fetchall()

combined_result=executequery(sth)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`extend`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) instead of `append` - instead of treating the list as a single item to append, it takes all the items of one list and adds them to the other:

```
combined_result.extend(result)
```

Comment: what is the difference  between extend and append?

Comment: I described the difference in my answer - `append` treats the list as a single item; `extend` treats the list as multiple items. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/python-append-vs-extend